# How can I print an multidimensional array element by specifying the array position with an index?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, reference

I'm trying to print an element of a 2D array by designating it's location with an index. Say, I want to print location 3 which would be `String[1][0]` for my array.

```java
String[][] fruit = new String[2][2];
fruit[0][0] = "apple";  //position 1
fruit[0][1] = "banana"; //position 2
fruit[1][0] = "pear";   //position 3
fruit[1][1] = "melon";  //position 4
```

I would like to call `fruit[1][0]` position 3 so when I ask to print "position 3" it gives me "pear".

Comment: ufff, read it twice and still do not understand what you mean. :-) if you want to have a relationship between the [ii][jj] o your 2D array and a 1D index, then you could use ```idx= ii * ncol + jj; ``` to get an index from ii,jj, and ```ii = (int)Math.Floor((double)(index / ncol));   jj = index % ncol;``` to get ii,jj from the index. So position 3 for example will be cell([1][0]) as in your example. You can also use a loop with a counter and a break. If that is what you are doing and is not working maybe you could post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is obviously the literal position of a cell since arrays start from an index value of 0. You also need to keep in mind that a 2D Array can possibly have different number of columns for any given row. The first and second rows for example may have 4 columns, the fifth row might have 6 columns, and the sixth, seventh row may have 4 columns again. Unless you know **for sure** that all columns within the Array are indeed fixed to a specific length (a "square" 2D Array), I can't see an advantage to this scheme.

Never the less, this can be easily done with two **for** loops (one nested within the other), for example:

```
String[][] array = {
        {"cell 1", "cell 2"},               // Row 1 (index 0)
        {"cell 3", "cell 4", "cell 5"},     // Row 2 (index 1)
        {"cell 6", "cell 7"}};              // Row 3 (index 2)

int yourDesiredCell = 5;

int cellCount = 0;
boolean found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        cellCount++;
        if (cellCount == yourDesiredCell) {
            System.out.println(array[i][j]);
            found = true;
            break;
            //return array[i][j];
        }
    }
    if (found) {
        break;
    }
}
```

You could also place this into a class method, for example:

```
public static String getCellData(String[][] array, int yourDesiredCell) {
    int cellCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            cellCount++;
            if (cellCount == yourDesiredCell) {
                return array[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Another method that could be handy is retrieving the total number of actual cells contained within the 2D Array (if you don't already know):

```
public static int getTotalCellCount(String[][] array) {
    int cellCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            cellCount++;
        }
    }
    return cellCount;
}
```

Comment: I'm really thankful. The first method was what I tried to do but could not make it work. I know a 2 by 2 seems weird but its for simplicity sake. Thank you very much i really needed a hand with that.

Answer (score 0):

What I got from your question was that there is a multi-dimensional array `A` of size say `nxm` where `n` is number of rows and'm`is number of columns. You want to get let say 1st element which will be`A[0][0]`, but you don't know how to convert` 1` into indices for the array.

Lets do this for a 2d array `A` of size `nxm`, then you can extend it to 3d etc too. Remember that each `A[i]` is an array of'm`elements, hence the position of row where the element is`x/m`,` i=x/m`. No need to make it 0-indexed because the integer division of java does that for you. If` i>=n`, then we should say element is not present.

Now you have to decide the position of the element in m elements. Hence j or position of the column is `x%m`. This will give you index b/w `0` and `m-1` which is correct range of `j`, but for an element in the first place it should give `0`, but it's giving `1`. Hence it js not 0-indexed. So `j= x%m -1` but for `(m-1)`th element its giving
`-1` as `x` would be divisible by m or `x%m=0`. So use ternary operator here, `j = x%m-1 <  0 ? m-1 : x%m-1`.

```
 i = x/m ;
 if(i<n){
     j = x%m -1 < 0 ? m-1 : x%m -1 ;
 }else{
    System.out.println("Element " +m+" does not exist") ;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, I'll check out this method later to understand it better. I really needed a hand so a appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest another approach with a **time complexity O(n)**.

```
public String getByPosition(int pos,String[][] mulArr){
   int row,col;
   int temp = pos;
   while(temp % mulArr.length != 0)temp++;
     row = (temp / mulArr.length) - 1;
     col = ((pos % mulArr[0].length) - 1 < 0) ? mulArr[0].length - 1 : (pos % mulArr[0].length) - 1;
   return mulArr[row][col];    
}
```